# Doubly linked list - Update list->tail after a merge sort

Tags: c, linked-list, mergesort

In an implementation of a doubly linked list I am using the typical structure:

```
struct node
{
    void *data;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
};
```

I will also insert at the end of the list in O(1) time, so I have another `struct` storing the `head` and the `tail`:

```
struct linklist
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
    size_t size;
};
```

The program works as expected for all insert and delete operations, but I have a problem with the sort function, I am using the merge-sort algorithm, as I understand it is the most effective or one of the most effective to sort lists, the algorithm works well:

```
static struct node *split(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *fast = head;
    struct node *slow = head;

    while ((fast->next != NULL) && (fast->next->next != NULL))
    {
        fast = fast->next->next;
        slow = slow->next;
    }

    struct node *temp = slow->next;

    slow->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

static struct node *merge(struct node *first, struct node *second, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        return second;
    }
    if (second == NULL)
    {
        return first;
    }
    if (comp(first->data, second->data) < 0)
    {
        first->next = merge(first->next, second, comp);
        first->next->prev = first;
        first->prev = NULL;
        return first;
    }
    else
    {
        second->next = merge(first, second->next, comp);
        second->next->prev = second;
        second->prev = NULL;
        return second;
    }
}

static struct node *merge_sort(struct node *head, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    if ((head == NULL) || (head->next == NULL))
    {
        return head;
    }

    struct node *second = split(head);

    head = merge_sort(head, comp);
    second = merge_sort(second, comp);
    return merge(head, second, comp);
}
```

but I have no idea how to keep the address of `list->tail` updated:

```
void linklist_sort(struct linklist *list, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    list->head = merge_sort(list->head, comp);
    // list->tail is no longer valid at this point
}
```

Sure I can walk the whole list after ordering and update `list->tail` by brute force, but I'd like to know if there's a fancier way to do it.

I managed to solve the problem using a circular list, but I would like to avoid changing the structure of the program.

Comment: The merge sort works by spliting the list, but giving all the terms to the same side while they maintain the order, then you switch sides and begin giving terms to the other side.  Then you merge both sides, and repeat until you split the list into just one list.  But here, you are giving each node to a different side... you are scrambling the list.... not ordering at all...  All the ordering you do in the merge phase is broken in the split part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm uses O(N) stack space by recursing in the `merge` function for every step. With this method, it would be very cumbersome to keep track of the `tail` node. You can simply scan the list to find it and update the `list` structure in `linklist_sort`. This extra step does not change the complexity of the sorting operation. You can save some time by starting from the current value of `link->tail`: the loop will stop immediately if the list was already sorted.

Here is a modified version:

```c
void linklist_sort(struct linklist *list, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *)) {
    list->head = merge_sort(list->head, comp);
    if (list->tail) {
        struct node *tail = list->tail;
        while (tail->next)
            tail = tail->next;
        list->tail = tail;
    }
}
```

Sorting linked lists with merge sort should only use **O(log(N))** space and **O(N log(N))** time.

Here are some ideas to improve this algorithm:

- since you know the length of the list, you don't need to scan the full list for splitting. You can just pass the lengths along with the list pointers and use that to determine where to split and only scan half the list.
- if you convert `merge` to a non-recursive version, you can keep track of the last node in the merge phase and update a pointer `struct node **tailp` passed as an argument to point to this last node. This would save the last scan, and removing the recursion will lower the space complexity. Whether this improves efficiency is not obvious, benchmarking will tell.
- from experience, sorting a linked list, singly and, a fortiori, doubly linked, is more efficiently implemented with an auxiliary array N pointers to the list nodes. You would sort this array and relink the nodes according to the order of the sorted array. The extra requirement is **O(N)** size.

Here is a modified version using the list lengths and with a non-recursive `merge`:

```c
struct node {
    void *data;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
};

struct linklist {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
    size_t size;
};

static struct node *split(struct node *head, size_t pos) {
    struct node *slow = head;

    while (pos-- > 1) {
        slow = slow->next;
    }
    struct node *temp = slow->next;
    slow->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

static struct node *merge(struct node *first, struct node *second,
                          int (*comp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *prev = NULL;
    struct node **linkp = &head;

    for (;;) {
        if (first == NULL) {
            second->prev = prev;
            *linkp = second;
            break;
        }
        if (second == NULL) {
            first->prev = prev;
            *linkp = first;
            break;
        }
        if (comp(first->data, second->data)) <= 0 {
            first->prev = prev;
            prev = *linkp = first;
            linkp = &first->next;
        } else {
            second->prev = prev;
            prev = *linkp = second;
            linkp = &second->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

static struct node *merge_sort(struct node *head, size_t size,
                               int (*comp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    if (size < 2) {
        return head;
    }

    struct node *second = split(head, size / 2);

    head = merge_sort(head, size / 2, comp);
    second = merge_sort(second, size - size / 2, comp);
    return merge(head, second, comp);
}

void linklist_sort(struct linklist *list, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *)) {
    list->head = merge_sort(list->head, comp, list->size);
    if (list->tail) {
        struct node *tail = list->tail;
        while (tail->next)
            tail = tail->next;
        list->tail = tail;
    }
}
```

Note that you could also simplify the `merge` function and not update the back pointers during the sort as you can relink the whole list during the last scan. This last scan would be longer and less cache friendly but it should still be more efficient and less error prone.

Comment: A [bottom up merge sort for linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) is a bit faster, since it doesn't involve any scanning to split list.

Comment: @rcgldr: Good point of course! Bottom up merge sort should be more efficient because there is no scanning to split the lists and it is also somewhat more cache friendly. It would also help to not split the lists at all by comparing to the tail node instead of to `NULL`, which would require keeping track of the end nodes but would save the final scan.

Comment: Using a circular list with a dummy node means there's always a node before and after any run. If the list itself is never split, then the merge checks for end of run by comparing against the pointer parameters: (start of 1st run, end of 1st run == start of 2nd run, end of 2nd run).

Comment: For bottom up merge sort using an array of pointers, start of 1st run = current array element, end of first run == start of 2nd run = 1st prior non-empty array element, end of 2nd run == 2nd prior non-empty array element or a local pointer to end of list. This is mostly an issue when merging the array of pointers to runs into a single run. This required realizing that the right most run is at array[0], and left most run is at array[max used] (the higher the array index, the more to the left of the list).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to merge sort the nodes as if they were single list nodes, then make a one time pass when done to set the previous pointers, and update the tail pointer.

Another option would use something similar to C++ std::list and std::list::sort. A circular doubly linked list is used. There is one dummy node that uses "next" as "head" and "prev" as "tail". The parameters to merge sort and merge are iterators or pointers, and only used to keep track of run boundaries, as nodes are merged by moving them within the original list. The merge function merges nodes from a second run into the first run, using std::list::splice. The logic is if first run element is less than or equal to second run element, just advance the iterator or pointer to the first run, else remove the node from the second run and insert it before the current node in the first run. This will automatically update the head and tail pointers in the dummy node if involved in a remove + insert step.

Changing struct node to :

```
struct node
{
    struct node *next;           // used as head for dummy node
    struct node *prev;           // used as tail for dummy node
    void *data;
};
```

would be a bit more generic.

Since the dummy node is allocated when a list is created, then begin == dummy->next, last == dummy-> prev, and end == dummy.

Comment: Thank you, I like very much the idea of the dummny nodes and its an optimal solution, but I see a problem: you always need to pass a comparison function to the `push`, `pop` ... functions, of course you can pass a dummy comparison function but I prefer to keep the API as is. Thanks again!

Comment: On the other hand I can pass the comparison function to the constructor and keep the rest of the API as is, yeah, definitely a very good idea.

Comment: @DavidRanieri - why would push and pop need a comparison function?

Comment: _... is less than or equal to second run element..._

Comment: @DavidRanieri - I don't understand, would you be using pop and push as a way to rearrange nodes during a sort? If so, note that the compare is done before any node is rearranged.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the best person to provide deep analysis concerning algorithms *Big-O* notation. Anyways, answering to a question with an already accepted "canonic" answer is great, because there's the possibility to explore alternative solutions without too much pressure.
This it interesting even if, as you will see, **the analysed solution is not better than the current solution presented in the question**.

---

The strategy starts by wondering if it is possible keeping track of the candidate tail element without turning the code upside down. The main candidate is the function deciding the order of the nodes in the sorted list: the `merge()` function.

Now, since after the comparison we decide which node will come first in the sorted list, we will have a *"loser"* that will be nearer to the tail. So, with a further comparison with the current tail element for each step, in the end we will be able to update the `tail` element with the *"loser of the losers"*.

The merge function will have the additional `struct node **tail` parameter (the double pointer is required because we will change the list `tail` field *in place*:

```
static struct node *merge(struct node *first, struct node *second, struct node **tail, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        return second;
    }
    if (second == NULL)
    {
        return first;
    }
    if (comp(first->data, second->data) < 0)
    {
        first->next = merge(first->next, second, tail, comp);

        /* The 'second' node is the "loser". Let's compare current 'tail' 
           with it, and in case it loses again, let's update  'tail'.      */
        if( comp(second->data, (*tail)->data) > 0)
            *tail = second;
        /******************************************************************/

        first->next->prev = first;
        first->prev = NULL;
        return first;
    }
    else
    {
        second->next = merge(first, second->next, tail, comp);

        /* The 'first' node is the "loser". Let's compare current 'tail' 
           with it, and in case it loses again, let's update  'tail'.      */
        if( comp(first->data, (*tail)->data) > 0)
            *tail = first;
        /******************************************************************/

        second->next->prev = second;
        second->prev = NULL;
        return second;
    }
}
```

There are no more changes required to the code, except those for the "propagation" of the `tail` double pointer parameter through `merge_sort()` and `linklist_sort()` functions:

```
static struct node *merge_sort(struct node *head, struct node **tail, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *));

void linklist_sort(List_t *list, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    list->head = merge_sort(list->head, &(list->tail), comp);
}
```

---

### The test

In order to test this modification I had to write a basic `insert()` function, a `compare()` function designed to obtain a sorted list in descending order, and a `printList()` utility. Then I wrote a main program to test all the stuff.

I did several tests; here I present just an example, in which I omit the functions presented in the question and above in this answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    void *data;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
} Node_t;

typedef struct linklist
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
    size_t size;
} List_t;

void insert(List_t *list, int data)
{
    Node_t * newnode = (Node_t *) malloc(sizeof(Node_t) );
    int * newdata = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *newdata = data;

    newnode->data = newdata;
    newnode->prev = list->tail;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if(list->tail)
        list->tail->next = newnode;

    list->tail = newnode;

    if( list->size++ == 0 )
        list->head = newnode;   
}

int compare(const void *left, const void *right)
{
    if(!left && !right)
        return 0;

    if(!left && right)
        return 1;
    if(left && !right)
        return -1;

    int lInt = (int)*((int *)left), rInt = (int)*((int *)right);

    return (rInt-lInt); 
}

void printList( List_t *l)
{
    for(Node_t *n = l->head; n != NULL; n = n->next )
    {
        printf( " %d ->", *((int*)n->data));
    }
    printf( " NULL (tail=%d)\n", *((int*)l->tail->data));
}


int main(void)
{
  List_t l = { 0 };

  insert( &l, 5 );
  insert( &l, 3 );
  insert( &l, 15 );
  insert( &l, 11 );
  insert( &l, 2 );
  insert( &l, 66 );
  insert( &l, 77 );
  insert( &l, 4 );
  insert( &l, 13 );
  insert( &l, 9 );
  insert( &l, 23 );

  printList( &l );

  linklist_sort( &l, compare );

  printList( &l );

  /* Free-list utilities omitted */

  return 0;
}
```

In this specific test I got the following output:

```
 5 -> 3 -> 15 -> 11 -> 2 -> 66 -> 77 -> 4 -> 13 -> 9 -> 23 -> NULL (tail=23)
 77 -> 66 -> 23 -> 15 -> 13 -> 11 -> 9 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> NULL (tail=2)
```

---

### Conclusions

- The good news is that theoretically speaking we still have an algorithm that, in the worst case, will have **O(N log(N))** time complexity.
- The bad news is that, to avoid a linear search in  a linked list (N "simple steps"), we have to do **N*logN** comparisons, involving a call to a function. **This makes the linear search still a better option**.

Comment: It have been very educational for me writing this analysis. Don't be to harsh to me for having put so much effort for a sub-optimal solution. ;)

Comment: That's great Roberto, thanks!! It works like a charm.

Comment: _This makes the linear search still a better option_ You are right, a linear search takes few milliseconds less with 100000 records.